# OpenCV на одном и том-же объекте находит разные контуры

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Мои объекты начали находится по разному, в то время как раньше они определялись строго квадратом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def min_example():
    img = cv2.imread('./res.png')
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 90, 180, 0)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for cnt in contours:
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)  # вписываем прямоугольник
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)  # поиск четырех вершин прямоугольника
        box = np.int0(box)  # округление координат
        cv2.drawContours(img, [box], 0, (255, 0, 0), 1)
cv2.imshow('contours', img) 
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

min_example()
```

В итоге позиция этих объектов сместилась. Нужно получить на всех объектах такой-же результат как первый нижний аватар.

[Исходное изображение](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcpbJ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[boundingRect](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga103fcbda2f540f3ef1c042d6a9b35ac7)

```
im2,contours,hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
cnt = contours[0]
x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(cnt)
cv.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
```